# Change home menu title after login

Tags: menu, login, default

Before login, my default menu title displayed with "Feature". I want to change it to Dashboard after login.

Comment: If an answer provides a solution to your problem it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do this is to add another menu item, rather than try to change the existing one.

Then in menu manager change the access level on the *Feature* from the default 'Public' to 'Guest'. This means it will not be visible for users that are logged in. Then change the access level on the new Dashboard menu item to 'Registered' so that only logged in users can see it.